# PHP: set the value of an HTML attribute equal to some JSON

Tags: php, html, json

I want to get some JSON in PHP, and set it as the value of an HTML attribute. How can I set the value without getting extra quotes?

1. Get JSON in PHP:

   `$my_stuff = array('don', 'matt', 'kate');`

   `$my_json = json_encode($my_stuff);`
2. Set it to an HTML attribute:

   `<input type="text" data-source=<?php echo $my_json; ?> name="typeahead-for-names">`

This should be simple but the resulting HTML has quotes around its outer brackets, which is wrong:

`<input type="text" data-source="["don","matt","kate"]">`

This is correct:

`<input type="text" data-source=["don","matt","kate"]>`

For context, this is being used with twitter-bootstrap's typeahead js. You may inspect the typeahead here to see what end result I am looking for: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: That's actually supposed to happen, It's quoting the values in the object. You might be able to use `str_replace("\"", "'", $my_json)` to replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: This `data-source=["don","matt","kate"]` is not correct. It's not valid HTML

Comment: What is the final purpose of this? There is probably going to be a better way than cramming the data into the HTML itself. I assume this is going to be used in some Javascript once the document has been loaded?

Comment: While @Pekka웃 is correct, the code as you have it should not be producing the quotes. See [this codepad](http://codepad.org/vINm9oat).

Comment: @Pekka웃 - this is for Twitter boostrap's typeahead - added a comment to the original post :)

Comment: @Joseph - interesting, it only seems to appear in my HTML attribute value, not if I just echo the string out as inner html. Ever heard of PHP adding quotes?

Comment: It may be your browser trying to do some smart stuff? PHP should not be adding the quotes here, there is no way for it to know you're setting an HTML attribute.

Comment: @Donny so you already have a jQuery `.load()` procedure somewhere? In that case, why not put it there instead of the HTML - `$("#elementname").data(["don","matt","kate"]);` or something to that effect should work

Comment: Also, what's the problem with quotes around it anyway? The example in the bootstrap docs does have quotes around it.